# Does hooking up two PATA devices on a single cable reduce performance?

Tags: hard-drive, pata

Presently, I have two PATA (Parallel ATA) devices installed in my computer.  One is an optical drive, the other is a hard drive.  Since my motherboard only has a single PATA connector, they are both connected to it with one cable.

I had never really thought there were any technical problems this setup before, though just now I was wondering: does a setup like this have any negative impact on performance?

Comment: I have answered your question. But I'm also curious, what kind of PC is this? Sounds like it goes way back! ;-)

Comment: It's actually a homemade gaming system I built myself.  The reason I use PATA devices though, is twofold.  The first is my bad luck with SATA devices.  I've had five of them brick after a month of use, and the brickings always occurred on bootup.  Two of the SATA devices, a hard drive and a DVD burner, bricked in unison.  I blame the cheap PSU I was using, which eventually failed a few days after its 3-year warranty expired.

Comment: My other reason is that unless you're using an SSD, SATA's generally provide no performance benefit, since the physical read/write speed of the PATA drive's platter(s) is actually slower than the speed of the interface.

Comment: Ah finally! Someone who has experience what I have - the bricking of HDDs by faulty power supply. I killed two SSDs thanks to a dodgy one. So sad. Anyway, SATA is meant to provide other performance benefits like *NCQ*, but *practically* speaking, I totally agree with you - unless you're running SSDs, PATA still does the trick and is plenty fast.

Comment: Which manufacturer was your PSU made by?  Mine was a Rosewill PSU.

Comment: Modern HDDs have a significant amount of on-board cache (64+ MB is common). This cache runs far faster than PATA can. Even without that, modern HDDs can reach or even exceed PATA max transfer rates with sequential R/W, especially considering protocol overhead. There are also other issues with using PATA, including lack of support for AHCI power management. It's *not* a good idea to use PATA on a new system - your reliability issues are almost certainly due to issues other than PATA vs SATA. Even if something [seems to work](http://xkcd.com/1457), it doesn't mean it's the correct solution.

Comment: @Bob: I had already surmised what my problems were: a cheap PSU.  As I stated above, that PSU eventually failed and had to be replaced.  As for my current setup (which has had no hardware problems since the PSU failure in 2011), I am planning on installing my a SATA drive I have (which I had uninstalled before it could fail).  I'll be running a setup where my main drive's data gets periodically synced to the SATA drive, and if it is still working after a month, I'll switch to it as my main drive... and keep the old as a backup.

Comment: @Bob I love theory vs reality stuff. The reality, as I've experienced it, is that most desktop workloads are small random read/writes for which PATA is more than enough. SATA's *NCQ* should make a difference, yet the reality is that I struggle to *notice* any difference between SATA and PATA. I suppose that the best platter drives aren't even made as PATA anymore, but that aside, PATA still does the job pretty well.

Comment: @Bob - What does "SATA's generally provide no performance benefit, since the physical read/write speed of the PATA drive's platter(s) is actually slower than the speed of the interface" refer to?

Comment: @Motivated I did not make that claim. If anything, I refuted that claim.

Comment: @Bob - Sure. It isn't clear and seeing that you had responded i thought you may know what it refers to. For example, "since the physical read/write speed of the PATA drive's platter(s) is actually slower than the speed of the interface". Does it mean to say that if the transfer speed of the interface is 2MB/s the write speed in 1MB/s?

Comment: @Motivated They seem to be trying to say PATA's throughput (of e.g. 133 MB/s) is greater than what a HDD can manage, with the implication that the extra throughput offered by SATA has no benefit for HDDs. That's untrue (modern HDDs can manage 150 MB/s sequential) and even if it were true for throughput it doesn't cover the full performance story (which involves higher-speed cache on the HDD, plus SATA's support for command queuing, etc.).

Comment: @Bob - How does that compare to SSD?

Comment: As a note, some of my initial claims had come from a former friend who fed me a lot of misinformation regarding SATA drives, which I believed because every SATA device I put into my computer had mysteriously died after about a month of usage.  Years later, I figured out that all of the "dead" SATA devices were actually just fine.  The motherboard I was using apparently had faulty SATA ports that would burn out after a month of usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it *can* have negative impact.

An IDE/ATA/PATA channel can only deal with one request, to one device, at a time. If both devices are being used simultaneously, their requests are interleaved in a way that means the first device gets to go while the second waits, then the second device goes while the first waits.

Still, under real-world conditions you might not see any decrease in performance. How often are you using both devices intensively at the same time?

Some good reading on the subject:

http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/if/ide/confPerformance-c.html

Comment: I actually do not use both at once very often.  Generally when I'm using the optical drive, I'm not doing anything else (since I'm more than likely to be watching a movie), so disk activity would be very low.

Comment: You're all good then, nothing to worry about. Good luck with your build!

Answer (score 1):

To summarize an extract from the following link

They don't slow to the speed of the slower device but there is still a performance impact under heavy load.

Link and Extract below-

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA#Two_devices_on_one_cable.E2.80.94speed_impact

- Modern ATA adapters support independent device timing meaning your devices don't slow down to the speed of the slowest connected device
- Reads and writes are done one at a time but thanks to on board caching you likely won't notice a performance impact for most workloads
- Certain heavy work loads on a slow device can cause a performance impact on a second, faster device connected to the same cable